# encodeURIComponent синтаксис

Tags: jquery

Как правильно кусок кода засунуть в encodeURIComponent при отправке ajax запроса?

Сейчас так:

```
 data: 't='+encodeURIComponent('<div align="center"><span style="font:15px Arial; color:#9A9A9A; font-weight:bold; padding:0 5px 0 0;">Выберите серию для просмотра:</span> <select id="series" onchange="javascript:if(document.getElementById('film_main')) document.getElementById('film_main').src=this.value;" size="1"><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12192244">1 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12192242">2 серия</option><option value="ttp://rutube.ru/play/embed/12192241">3 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12195691">4 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12199572">5 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12203726">6 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12218073">7 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12222068">8 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12227374">9 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12232328">10 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12248946">11 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12253027">12 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12258691">13 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12262158">14 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12277378">15 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12280574">16 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12284125">17 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12288202">18 серия</option><option value="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12099022">19 серия</option></select><iframe allowfullscreen="true" frameborder="0" height="400" id="film_main" mozallowfullscreen="true" name="film_main" src="http://rutube.ru/play/embed/12192244" webkitallowfullscreen="true" width="600"></iframe></div>'),
```

Но естественно пишет ошибку:
**Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

Возможности менять содержимое html кода нет, как вы поняли.

Comment: но кавычки то в строке javascript надо экранировать (обратными косыми) и как бы без этого невозможно. И функция encode... тут как бы вообще не причем, это базовые требования синтаксиса языка

Comment: Нет возможности редактировать всё, что внутри encodeURIComponent

Comment: Что значит нет возможности, как эта строка туда попадает ? И причем тут html код, сам код останется тем же, но если он заключен в кавычки, то такие же кавычки внутри должны быть экрнированы

Comment: Это в материалах указано. Движок не позволяет произвести замену сразу во всех материалах (ucoz). Т.е. мы имеем: data: 't='+encodeURIComponent('$MESSAGE$'),

Comment: Вы как бы поймите, что ни один язык программирования не способен понять, где заканчивается литерал, если он выглядит как `x = 'abc ' def '` как бы тут и человек не очень то поймет, что кавычка включена внутрь кавычек

Comment: Я понимаю. Поэтому и написал сюда. Предположил, что есть выход. Как же быть тогда.

Comment: Так как прямого решения по понятным причинам нет и быть не может, то вероятно надо более подробно описать основную задачу, что за движок такой, с какой целью происходит вставка блока html в JS, как именно она выполняется со стороны движка и т.п. возможно вашу задачу надо и можно решить совершенно другими способами, не связанными с подстановкой не экранированной строки в код